# SQApplication Express (Apex) - Displaying the result from cascading list of values (LOV) selection

Tags: sql, express, oracle-apex, lov

I have been working on this for a while now and am stuck on finding the solution.

This is what I would like the end result to be - displaying this table below based on the selection from LOV #1 AND LOV #2:

[image: PIC 1]

This is what I have so far:

[image: PIC 2]

How do I make the page to display the result of the 2nd LOV selection into the likeness of the first picture?

In other words, after the second LOV is chosen, I would like the third part (Column Names) to be displayed in a report format instead of selection list format.

I am on Apex version: 4.2.0.00.27

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a report which has your select list as a bind variable and your SQL query using the select list in the where clause. Create a dynamic action on your select list for the OnChange event. You need to refresh the report in the dynamic action when triggering the event.